# How to install php7?

Tags: php, installation

Since php7 has been released, I wanted to try it out on my current machine.

I have tried building it from source using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/tronsha/b471dd6d73dc8ebae242#file-installphp7-sh) yet that fails for me (and I have posted the [error message](https://gist.github.com/tronsha/b471dd6d73dc8ebae242#gistcomment-1639993) in the thread).

Yet the question is not necessarily solving the compiling issue, but more basic:

How can I install php7?

I am on Ubuntu14.04, yet I would like for the answer to be operating-system-agnostic.

Comment: I don't know if `apt-get` is updated yet, have you tried `apt-get update` and tried installing `php7`? In any case, I'm prety sure the solution presented in https://gist.github.com/tronsha/b471dd6d73dc8ebae242 still works.

Comment: On askubuntu, there is a [dupe](https://askubuntu.com/questions/705880/how-to-install-php-7/705893#705893) and a related [question about future support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/704986/how-ubuntu-plans-to-support-php7)

Comment: @Havenard I tried it, it failed for me. Did you try yourself? :)

Comment: A couple of failed tests. Most of them expected. Your PHP7 will probably work fine. Except maybe not the curl extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **install php7 in ubuntu 14.04** system please follow mentioned below steps:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.0
```

**for use mysql**

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

**If you want to remove php5  then after installation of php7 follow the steps mentioned below:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge php5-common -y
sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove -y
```

Comment: As Ondrey is the official owner of the PHP tree in Debian, the PPA is rather trustworthy. Still, one should take into account that additonal repositories may install everything and might pose a security risk. Bearing that in mind, I am also using it.

Answer (score 0):

I shared at https://jaimemontoya.com/learning-php-7/#20190807165248 the way I installed PHP Version 7.0.33-8 on Ubuntu 18.04.1. I also posted a screenshot of what my `<?php phpinfo();?>` returned after the successful installation. See below the steps I followed:

```
root@jaimemontoya:/# pwd
/
root@jaimemontoya:/# apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 Co-installable PHP versions: PHP 5.6, PHP 7.x and most requested extensions are included. Only Supported Versions of PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided.

Debian oldstable and stable packages are provided as well: https://deb.sury.org/#debian-dpa

You can get more information about the packages at https://deb.sury.org

BUGS&FEATURES: This PPA now has a issue tracker:
https://deb.sury.org/#bug-reporting

CAVEATS:
1. If you are using php-gearman, you need to add ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman
2. If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
3. If you are using nginx, you are advise to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
   or ppa:ondrej/nginx

PLEASE READ: If you like my work and want to give me a little motivation, please consider donating regularly: https://donate.sury.org/

WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see 
https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:

# LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                        
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                         
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                                       
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                                  
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease [20.8 kB]         
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages [697 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [7,024 B]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages [983 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe Translation-en [299 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [11.9 kB]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 Packages [577 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe Translation-en [189 kB]
Get:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages [45.2 kB]     
Get:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en [22.1 kB]
Fetched 3,029 kB in 2s (1,515 kB/s)         
Reading package lists... Done
root@jaimemontoya:/# apt-get update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                        
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                 
Hit:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                                
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                  
Reading package lists... Done
root@jaimemontoya:/# apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpcre3 php-common php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-json php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
Suggested packages:
  php-pear
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  php-common php7.0 php7.0-cli php7.0-common php7.0-fpm php7.0-json php7.0-mysql php7.0-opcache php7.0-readline
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpcre3
1 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,047 kB of archives.
After this operation, 14.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpcre3 amd64 2:8.43-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [237 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php-common all 2:69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3 [15.1 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.0-common amd64 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [897 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.0-json amd64 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [17.2 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.0-opcache amd64 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [79.1 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.0-readline amd64 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.6 kB]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.0-cli amd64 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,300 kB]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.0-fpm amd64 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,307 kB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.0 all 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [56.3 kB]
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.0-mysql amd64 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [125 kB]
Fetched 4,047 kB in 4s (916 kB/s)  
(Reading database ... 169946 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpcre3_2%3a8.43-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcre3:amd64 (2:8.43-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) over (2:8.39-9) ...
Setting up libpcre3:amd64 (2:8.43-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php-common.
(Reading database ... 169946 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-php-common_2%3a69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking php-common (2:69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-common.
Preparing to unpack .../1-php7.0-common_7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-common (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-json.
Preparing to unpack .../2-php7.0-json_7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-json (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-opcache.
Preparing to unpack .../3-php7.0-opcache_7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-opcache (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-readline.
Preparing to unpack .../4-php7.0-readline_7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-readline (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../5-php7.0-cli_7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-cli (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-fpm.
Preparing to unpack .../6-php7.0-fpm_7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-fpm (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0.
Preparing to unpack .../7-php7.0_7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0 (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.0-mysql.
Preparing to unpack .../8-php7.0-mysql_7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.0-mysql (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up php-common (2:69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/phpsessionclean.timer → /lib/systemd/system/phpsessionclean.timer.
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.22) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up php7.0-common (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/calendar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ctype.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/exif.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/fileinfo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/ftp.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/gettext.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/iconv.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/phar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/posix.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/shmop.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sockets.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvsem.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/sysvshm.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/tokenizer.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-mysql (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/mysqli.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-readline (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/readline.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-opcache (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/opcache.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-json (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/json.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-cli (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.0 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar7.0 to provide /usr/bin/phar (phar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar.phar7.0 to provide /usr/bin/phar.phar (phar.phar) in auto mode

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini with new version
Setting up php7.0-fpm (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini with new version
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.0 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.0 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.0-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php7.0-fpm.service → /lib/systemd/system/php7.0-fpm.service.
Setting up php7.0 (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.22) ...
root@jaimemontoya:/# apt-get --purge autoremove -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
root@jaimemontoya:/# service php7.0-fpm start
root@jaimemontoya:/# php -v
PHP 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: May 31 2019 11:34:35) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
root@jaimemontoya:/# apt purge libapache2-mod-php7.0 libapache2-mod-php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'libapache2-mod-php' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libapache2-mod-php7.0' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
root@jaimemontoya:/# apt install libapache2-mod-php7.0 libapache2-mod-php
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php7.3 libpcre2-8-0 libsodium23 php7.3-cli php7.3-common php7.3-json php7.3-opcache php7.3-readline
Suggested packages:
  php-pear
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-php libapache2-mod-php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.3 libpcre2-8-0 libsodium23 php7.3-cli php7.3-common php7.3-json php7.3-opcache php7.3-readline
0 upgraded, 10 newly installed, 0 to remove and 40 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,439 kB of archives.
After this operation, 22.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.3-common amd64 7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [938 kB]
Get:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.3-json amd64 7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [18.4 kB]
Get:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.3-opcache amd64 7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [182 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.3-readline amd64 7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [12.0 kB]
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libpcre2-8-0 amd64 10.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [191 kB]
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libsodium23 amd64 1.0.17-0.1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [147 kB]
Get:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 php7.3-cli amd64 7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,378 kB]
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php7.3 amd64 7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,324 kB]
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php all 2:7.3+69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3 [6,244 B]
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libapache2-mod-php7.0 amd64 7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 [1,242 kB]
Fetched 5,439 kB in 5s (1,094 kB/s)               
Selecting previously unselected package php7.3-common.
(Reading database ... 170110 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-php7.3-common_7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.3-common (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.3-json.
Preparing to unpack .../1-php7.3-json_7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.3-json (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.3-opcache.
Preparing to unpack .../2-php7.3-opcache_7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.3-opcache (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.3-readline.
Preparing to unpack .../3-php7.3-readline_7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.3-readline (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpcre2-8-0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libpcre2-8-0_10.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpcre2-8-0:amd64 (10.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libsodium23:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libsodium23_1.0.17-0.1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsodium23:amd64 (1.0.17-0.1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package php7.3-cli.
Preparing to unpack .../6-php7.3-cli_7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking php7.3-cli (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php7.3.
Preparing to unpack .../7-libapache2-mod-php7.3_7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php7.3 (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php.
Preparing to unpack .../8-libapache2-mod-php_2%3a7.3+69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php (2:7.3+69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-php7.0.
Preparing to unpack .../9-libapache2-mod-php7.0_7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up php7.3-common (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/calendar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/ctype.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/exif.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/fileinfo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/ftp.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/gettext.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/iconv.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/pdo.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/phar.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/posix.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/shmop.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/sockets.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/sysvmsg.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/sysvsem.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/sysvshm.ini with new version

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/tokenizer.ini with new version
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.0 (7.0.33-8+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini with new version
Module mpm_event disabled.
Enabling module mpm_prefork.
apache2_switch_mpm Switch to prefork
apache2_invoke: Enable module php7.0
Setting up php7.3-opcache (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/opcache.ini with new version
Setting up libsodium23:amd64 (1.0.17-0.1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Setting up php7.3-readline (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/readline.ini with new version
Setting up libpcre2-8-0:amd64 (10.33-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
Setting up php7.3-json (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/mods-available/json.ini with new version
Setting up php7.3-cli (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/php7.3 to provide /usr/bin/php (php) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar7.3 to provide /usr/bin/phar (phar) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/phar.phar7.3 to provide /usr/bin/phar.phar (phar.phar) in auto mode

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/cli/php.ini with new version
Setting up libapache2-mod-php7.3 (7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

Creating config file /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini with new version
libapache2-mod-php7.3: php7.0 module already enabled, not enabling PHP 7.3
Setting up libapache2-mod-php (2:7.3+69+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+2+php7.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
root@jaimemontoya:/#
```

**UPDATE 1:**

As you requested it k0pernikus, literally how it was published in Chapter 1 of Learning PHP 7, by Antonio Lopez, published by Packt Publishing:

> Installing PHP
>
> The only thing to consider in this section is to remove any previous
>   PHP versions on your system. To do so, you can run the following
>   command:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get -y purge php.*`
>
> The next step is to add the necessary repositories in order to fetch
>   the correct PHP version. The commands to add and update them are:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`
>
> `$ sudo LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php -y`
>
> `$ sudo apt-get update`
>
> Finally, we need to install PHP 7 together with the driver for MySQL.
>   For this, just execute the following three commands:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get install php7.0 php7.0-fpm php7.0-mysql -y`
>
> `$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove -y`
>
> `$ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove -y`
>
> `$ sudo service php7.0-fpm start`

Comment: Can you please reduce the output to the actual commands being entered? You have ten commands, the rest is only their output (which is not necessary to post in their entirety). Only post the output of a command if it's really meaningful. With that in mind, I fail to see the difference to [kamlesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35691579/457268) answer, as this appears to also be using the `ondrej/php` ppa approach.

Comment: @k0pernikus Done. See my UPDATE 1.